# Getting error when click on imageswitcher

Tags: java, android

When click on imageswitcher , getting error classcastexception that is show in logcat. please help me guys
The code i am using when click on imageswitcher

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //List<String> it;
                  imageId = parent.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
                try {}
}
```

and i am using this image id

```
imageView.setLayoutParams( new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        imageView.setImageResource((int) imageid);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

05-17 19:04:40.053: W/dalvikvm(5956): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3123)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-17 19:04:40.092: E/AndroidRuntime(5956):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another one of Eclipse's fumbles. Just clean your project once and it'll rebuild your `R.java` file.

**Update 1**

I don't get why you're explicitly typecasting `imageid`. Just use `int imageid= R.drawable.somepic`

**Update 2**

Try changing `getItemId` to `getResourceId`.

Comment: I have already done to clean and rebuild but nothing to change

Comment: What is `imageid`? And what type is it? If you're accessing a resource file then check my answer.

Comment: imageId = parent.getAdapter().getItemId(position); when select the image from gallery

Comment: Actually i want to view this image enlarge how to make this?

Comment: but in above comment it return long only imageid

Comment: You could make an activity with an imageView that fits the parent. Set the image to that imageView.

Comment: It shouldn't return a long. Ids are ALWAYS of the integer type. Please post the code of the function returning the imageid.

Comment: can you give me any example please!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30134/discussion-between-torcellite-and-sunil)